Como soluciono el error uninitialized constant Nokogiri::HTML4 (NameError) en Ruby in Rails
Comence a aprender ruby on rails recientemente
Utilizo ruby version 2.2.1 and rails version 4.2.7.1
Cuando creo un nuevo proyecto y trato de ejecutar
rails generate scaffold post title:string body:text
obtengo este error
/home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/loofah-2.21.1/lib/loofah/html4/document.rb:10:in `module:HTML4': uninitialized constant Nokogiri::HTML4 (NameError)
No entiendo mucho porque recién estoy aprendiendo y no domino absolutamente nada
Por favor ayuda

*** LOCAL GEMS ***
nokogiri (1.9.1, 1.6.8.1)

Asumo que estás aprendiendo en un proyecto existente, porque las versiones que mencionas son antiquisimas, sin mencionar que nokogiri no es parte de un proyecto rails por defecto. Es dificil darte una respuesta por la poca información que entregas, pero ¿has instalado las gemas parte  del proyecto previamente? eso lo realizas ejecutando en un terminal bundle install en la carptea de tu proyecto.

Si por desgracia tengo que usar esas versiones, pero lo que estaba probando era crear una app demo desde cero para familiarizarme con el lenguaje y el framework. Si probé actualizar las gemas porque cuando vi con gem query estaba instalada. Supongo que la versión de nokogiri para esa app que estaba intentando crear con las veriones que tengo de ruby y rails no sean compatibles .... ni idea
